# Ruby If Else syntax evaluation

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I don't understand why my If else statement doesn't work properly, if I the input 'y' then it evaluates the last part of the if else statement.

```
puts('give 1: ')
nr1= Integer(gets)
puts('give 2: ')
nr2= Integer(gets)

selection = gets.to_s

if (selection == "y".upcase)
  puts "Result is #{nr1+nr2}"
elsif (selection =="v".upcase)
  puts "Result is #{nr1-nr2}"
else (selection == "k".upcase)
  puts "Result is #{nr1*nr2}"
end
```

Comment: `else (selection == "k".upcase)` will be treated as plain `else`. Probably you want `elsif` in place.

Comment: I did try switching it but it does not have any effect, it does not print the result if i input 'y' ,'v' or 'k'.

Comment: You want `if selection.chomp.downcase == "y"` (or `if selection.chomp.upcase == "Y"`). `gets.to_s` is the same as `gets`. `gets` always returns a string that ends with a newline (`"\n"`). You need `gets.chomp` to remove that newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing [`#chomp`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp) method. As `\n` is appended to the STDIN which you can remove using `#chomp`.

```
2.2.2 :032 > selection = gets
y
 => "y\n"
2.2.2 :033 > selection.chomp
 => "y"
```

You can update your code as follows:

```
selection = gets.to_s.chomp.upcase

if selection == 'Y'
  puts "Result is #{nr1+nr2}"
elsif selection == 'V'
  puts "Result is #{nr1-nr2}"
elsif selection == 'K'
  puts "Result is #{nr1*nr2}"
else
  puts 'Invalid input'
end
```

Although, ruby `case` will suit best here. Something like:

```
case selection.upcase
when 'Y'
  puts "Result is #{nr1 + nr2}"
when 'V'
  puts "Result is #{nr1 - nr2}"
when 'K'
  puts "Result is #{nr1 * nr2}"
else
  puts "Invalid input. Please provide a valid input [Y/V/K]"
end
```

Comment: Can `"y".upcase` be simplified? Is that really what you want? Any why `to_s` in `gets.to_s.chomp`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, there's no need for `#to_s`. Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `if selection.upcase == "Y"` is what is intended here.

Answer (score 4):

A good habit to get into is breaking this out into a proper `case` statement:

```
case (selection.upcase)
when 'Y'
  puts "Result is #{nr1+nr2}"
when 'V'
  puts "Result is #{nr1-nr2}"
when 'K'
  puts "Result is #{nr1*nr2}"
else
  puts "I don't know what you mean."
end
```

Now it's important to note that `selection == "y".upcase` compares `selection` to `"Y"`, it doesn't upcase your selection. I've adjusted that here do to a case-insensitive match on `selection` by using that as the thing the `case` is operating on.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was that I was inputting 'y' and the if statement was waiting for uppercase 'Y' which is why it did not execute.

Comment: Yeah, you almost had it, but things were a bit jumbled up. Hope this helped clarify.

Comment: @CarySwoveland A look-up table mapping string to operation and using `send` would be a better solution here, absolutely.

Comment: Another option is to use a hash. `h = { 'Y'=>:+, 'V'=>:-, 'K'=>:* }; selection = gets.chomp.upcase; puts "Result is #{nr1.send(h[selection], nr2)}" if h.key?(selection)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You should probably add that as an alternate answer just for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a hash.

```
h = { 'Y'=>:+, 'V'=>:-, 'K'=>:* }
selection = gets.chomp.upcase
puts "Result is #{nr1.public_send(h[selection], nr2)}" if h.key?(selection)
```